# Deploy to App Engine fails with 'Step #0: No .deps.json file found for the app'

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, .net-core, google-cloud-platform

It has been a few months since I last deployed a new version of my .NET Core 2.1 app engine service. For some reason this no longer works:

```
BUILD
Starting Step #0
Step #0: Pulling image: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/aspnetcorebuild@sha256:f5552a5efdaf278a3124ea10fd1c9636b09fc9f98f9e620cbd71279797576b3f
Step #0: sha256:f5552a5efdaf278a3124ea10fd1c9636b09fc9f98f9e620cbd71279797576b3f: Pulling from gcp-runtimes/aspnetcorebuild
Step #0: bd0de8be231c: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: 091745073ef1: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: 355bf594d611: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: 013d0752935b: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: 4c7d0d02eb09: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: 013d0752935b: Waiting
Step #0: 4c7d0d02eb09: Waiting
Step #0: 355bf594d611: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: 355bf594d611: Download complete
Step #0: 013d0752935b: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: 013d0752935b: Download complete
Step #0: 4c7d0d02eb09: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: 4c7d0d02eb09: Download complete
Step #0: 091745073ef1: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: 091745073ef1: Download complete
Step #0: bd0de8be231c: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: bd0de8be231c: Download complete
Step #0: bd0de8be231c: Pull complete
Step #0: 091745073ef1: Pull complete
Step #0: 355bf594d611: Pull complete
Step #0: 013d0752935b: Pull complete
Step #0: 4c7d0d02eb09: Pull complete
Step #0: Digest: sha256:f5552a5efdaf278a3124ea10fd1c9636b09fc9f98f9e620cbd71279797576b3f
Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/aspnetcorebuild@sha256:f5552a5efdaf278a3124ea10fd1c9636b09fc9f98f9e620cbd71279797576b3f
Step #0: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/aspnetcorebuild@sha256:f5552a5efdaf278a3124ea10fd1c9636b09fc9f98f9e620cbd71279797576b3f
Step #0: No .deps.json file found for the app
Finished Step #0
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/aspnetcorebuild@sha256:f5552a5efdaf278a3124ea10fd1c9636b09fc9f98f9e620cbd71279797576b3f" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cloud build failed. Check logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/55c47ed9-b131-4ca4-8f78-c1a75770e8f4?project=39816801693 Failure status: UNKNOWN: Error Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details
Failed to deploy project pmb.Web to App Engine Flex.
```

The project works fine when I run it locally in VS2019, but it crashes in Cloud Build. I use the Google Cloud Tools for Visual Studio extension to deploy the app. Running `gcloud app deploy` returns the same error.

I checked `pmb.Web\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1` and the `pmb.Web.deps.json` file seems to be there.

My unchanged app.yaml:

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

I have spent quite a bit of time trying to find a solution but have yet to find it.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although i am still not sure what the cause is, i did find the solution.

I changed `runtime: aspnetcore` to `runtime: custom` inside my `app.yaml`. And then I added a Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/aspnetcore:2.1
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "<Project Name>.dll"]
```

My best guess is that Google App Engine no longer supports .NET Core 2.1 without a docker file?

Comment: you are right, now I'm having the same issue to migrate from .netcore 3.1 to .net 5. Google gcr doesn't have public docker image published for .net 5 yet (see the full list here https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/google-appengine/global/aspnetcore). Your solution did the job!

Comment: I'm using the following Dockerfile: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "<Project Name>.dlll"]

Comment: I'm using .NET 6 and had the same initial error.  I started with just the dockerfile and then got the error:  A Dockerfile already exists in the workspace, this Dockerfile cannot be used with the aspnetcore runtime.